# 10th element in rating is not present so what should i do to print dash(-) in that place tto matchup the data frame

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.amazon.in/') 
search_item = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id ='twotabsearchtextbox']")
search_item.send_keys("Laptop")

serch_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='nav-search-submit-button']")
serch_btn.click()

cpu_filter = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Intel Core i7').click()
cpu2_filter = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Intel Core i9').click()

href = []
lnks1=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='a-link-normal a-text-normal']")
for lnk in lnks1:
    href.append(lnk.get_attribute('href'))
href = href[0:10]
print(len(href))

Rating = []
for i in href:
    driver.get(i)
    try:
        rating = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='reviewsMedley']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span/span")
        for i in rating:
            print(i.text)
    except:
            print('-')
```

I've tried the above code, but because the 10th element doesn't have any rating, I used try and except. However, it's not working. It's not reverting back the dash(-) and it is just printing the 9 elements.

I want 10th element as dash(-) so that I could match up with at the time of creating dataframe.

I am not getting any idea what to do next. Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

.text doesn't throw any exception it just retrieves what's present as the text content. If there is no content then it returns an empty string `''`

**You may use -**

```
for i in href:
    driver.get(i)
    rating = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='reviewsMedley']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/span/span")
    for i in rating:
       print(i.text if i.text!="" else "-")
```